# Setting specific values for page size and margins in Koma Script

Tags: margins, koma-script, scrbook, bleed

I am using a two-sided, a5 paper `scrbook` for a document where I need to meet very concrete specifications, i.e. the page size needs to have a bleed margin of 3mm, so the size would be totalling 154mm x 216mm.

I came across the following possible solutions:

- `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31976/143732)
- the `geometry` package as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249354/custom-papersize-and-layoutsize-for-springer-using-a-documentclass-svmult-an?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- setting the `paper` and let the `DIV` be calculated as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228122/143732)

However, the first one did not seem to work, and the second and third lead to problems with the text taking way less space than I thought it to do, [seemingly because of the fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204793/143732) of 10pt.

The first one does not seem to work at all, while setting the font to 10pt and using `paper=154mm:216` leads to this, which has too much margin:

[image]

and adding `DIV=calc` as leads to this result, which has too few margin:

[image: first page with visible margins]

I actually want the same margin I get when I specify `paper=A5` just with the smaller font and the added bleed:

[image: second page with visible margins]

So, what is the *appropriate* way to realize above specifications while not corrupting type area calculations or anything?

My code:

```
\documentclass[
    paper=154mm:216mm, %does not help
    DIV=calc, %does not help either 
    twoside, 
    fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{showframe} % added to make it easier to see the layout
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us a short compilable code with your actual settings for class `scrbook` ...  The given information yet is too less ...

Comment: I do not really understand the question. However: If you want special margins use package `geometry`. You can change every layout parameter, if use this package. So if you have a problem with it, you may have used the wrong parameters and should show a MWE and tell, what is wrong. `typearea` does set `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` on its own. If you want to change them manually, you should switch this off using option `pagesize=false`. See the manual for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
\usepackage[width=154truemm,height=216truemm,center]{crop}
```

does what you want:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
       twoside,
       a5paper,
       fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{showframe} % added to make it easier to see the layout
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[width=154truemm,height=216truemm,center]{crop}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```